# How to download my custom theme?

Tags: themes

I'm taking over a website that was previously managed by another person, which had installed a **self-made custom theme** (uploaded through .zip file). In other words, the theme is not available online. It was made for the website.

The person does not have the original files and I need to update it. Is it possible to reconstruct/download the theme so I can modify it offline and then re-upload it? I do not find anywhere a download option for the theme.

Alternatively, is it possible to bulk download the website and somehow reconstruct the theme? In principle, all should be there.

I know there are some related posts here but can't find the proper answer to my question.

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the server where the site is hosted?

Comment: @QStudio Probably. Is there a generic way to connect? I log in through mysite/wp-admin

Comment: Probably? Generic? FTP is usually secured by username / password, which is managed from the host control panel, but there are other means, including adding plugins to give FTP access.

Comment: @QStudio I was only given the login details for website admin. I am on Filezilla and tried to join to mysite.com but don't know which port to use. Still, it seems to work without port, but I get "Remote certificate not trusted."

Comment: That's normal for new hosts, trust it - if you want to..

Comment: Create a backup using a backup plugin like updraftplus, download the backup to your local server, and restore it. You will have the theme files as well as plugin, data, media files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download installed themes and plugins from the WordPress dashboard with a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-theme-plugin-download/

Comment: Thank you very much!! Actually, I found one plugin called Theme Editor which gave me direct access to all files, which is in the end what I needed (change a few of them). I can now change the files online rather than offline (download-change-upload)